# How to find the amount of ions from the dissociation of a weak acid?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution

Someone asked me this question,"How many ions are formed during the dissociation of 500 molecules of carbonic acid, if it dissociates in the first degree by 20%, and in the second degree by 1%?" and I don't understand this question. First degree? Second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "degree" is not well chosen, when not attached to the words "of dissociation". The "first degree" means that $20$% of the $\ce{H2CO3}$ molecules are dissociated into $\ce{H+ +  HCO3^-}$ ions. The "second degree" means that $1$% are dissociated into $\ce{2 H+ + CO3^{2-}}$ ions. Now use this information to calculate the amount of $\ce{H^+, HCO3^-}$ and $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ ions in this solution.

Comment: [Degree of dissociation](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/D01566) is the correct term with well-established definition, don't mislead the OP. There is no "probably" or need for arbitrary number of molecules whatsoever. Also, before answering the question, it's a good idea to check for answered duplicates.